# How to horizontally add panels to bootstrap grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Referring the this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jjpatel361/sgae5h76/6/show/)

I am having hard time understanding how to horizontally add panels without disturbing the grid.

```
----------------------------
|  Panel 1                 |   
____________________________ 
|          | Preview |  |  
|          | Preview |  |  
|          | Preview |  |
---------------------------
```

when you click on Preview a new panel (panel 2 overalayed) with the info should appear next to the current div and horizontal scroll bar should appear.

```
 ---------------------------------
|  Panel 1 |      Panel 2         |
 _________________________________|
|          |  panel 2 details     |  
|          |  panel 2 details     |
```

How to dynamically add panels to existing grid such that it extends horizontally. say I can add N panels and grid extends horizontally.

Comment: Use dynamic tabs of bootstrap instead. Sample code at http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_tabs_dynamic&stacked=h

Comment: nope tabs wont solve the problem as I want panel2 to appear when panel1 is clicked. and so on..